# Need SQL query to update the column using case when by joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables : Sales & Transaction. I need to update the INDICATOR column of the Sales table using CASE WHEN by joining these two tables.

Using below query but not working :

```
Update Sales a set 
a.indicator= 
CASE WHEN  a.retail_value >= t.selling_price then 'Y'
     WHEN  a.retail_value <  t.selling_price then 'N'
     ELSE NULL 
     END    
     FROM Transaction t 
     WHERE a.id = t.id and a.date <= t.date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this;

```
UPDATE a
SET a.indicator = CASE
                      WHEN  a.retail_value >= t.selling_price THEN 'Y'
                      ELSE 'N'
                  END
FROM Sales AS a
JOIN Transaction AS t
ON a.id = t.id
WHERE a.date <= t.date;
```

Comment: It's not working. 
Error : Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.MKDN_PRICE_IND = 
 CASE  
   WHEN  a.new_unit_retail >= t.TICKET_PRICe then 'Y'
 ' at line 1

Comment: can you try without using table alias names? try to use full names instead. it sometimes helps you to avoid unexpected issues when the query is complex or uncertain.

Comment: Not working without alias as well. :(

Comment: what is your MySQL version? and does new_unit_retail and TICKET_PRICe fields have the same data types?

Comment: yes, they both have the same datatype integer. server is 8.0

Comment: can you try once again with my updated answer?

Comment: How do we do it in Netezza database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to mention the **a.indicator** column after the **CASE** keyword. I feel the below query might work

```
 Update Sales a set 
 a.indicator = CASE a.indicator
 WHEN  a.retail_value >= t.selling_price then 'Y'
 WHEN  a.retail_value <  t.selling_price then 'N'
 ELSE NULL 
 END    
 FROM Transaction t 
 WHERE a.id = t.id and a.date <= t.date;
```

Comment: It's not working. 
Error : Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.MKDN_PRICE_IND = 
 CASE  
   WHEN  a.new_unit_retail >= t.TICKET_PRICe then 'Y'
 ' at line 1